# go build error" NEXT undefined (type *"database/sql".Rows has no field or method NEXT)

Tags: go

I want to use NEXT in rows in go but i'vw got warning in rows.NEXT
it said
NEXT undefined (type *"database/sql".Rows has no field or method NEXT)

```
     func FetchViewDO() (shipment_admin.ShipmentViewDetailDOGroup, error) {
            var obj ShipmentDOBaseModel
            var objg ShipmentDOGroup
            var arrobj []ShipmentDOBaseModel
            var res shipment_admin.ShipmentViewDetailDOGroup
        
            var db *sql.DB
        
            con := db
            sqlStatement := `SELECT s.status_id,sdog.*,sdo.shipment_id,sdo.external_id,sdo.client_code
        FROM shipment_delivery_order sdo
        LEFT JOIN shipment_delivery_order_group sdog ON sdog.shipment_child_id = sdo.shipment_id
        LEFT JOIN shipment s ON s.shipment_id = sdo.shipment_id`
        
            rows, err := con.Query(sqlStatement)
            defer rows.Close()
        
            if err != nil {
                return res, err
            }
        
            for rows.NEXT() {
                err = rows.Scan(&objg.ShipmentParentID, &objg.CreatedAt, &objg.ShipmentChildID)
                if err != nil {
                    return res, err
                }
            }
            res.Status = http.StatusOK
            res.Message = "Success"
            res.Data = arrobj
        
            return res, nil
        
        }
```

Comment: Why `NEXT` and not `Next`?

Comment: *"I want to use NEXT in rows"* -- You can't because [`*sql.Rows`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows) does *not* have a method with that name, and you also can't add methods to imported types, so the only option you have is to use methods that have been defined for that type. Also, in case you didn't know, Go is case sensitive. That means you can't use arbitrary casing of identifiers and expect them to be resolved by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method called NEXT, but there's a method called [Next](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Next) and i think it's the answer for your question, remember that Go is case sensitives